# Textwrangler: Move to next or previous word

Tags: macos, textwrangler

How do you move by word in TextWrangler (on OS X)? (just like vim's `b` and `w` keys when in command mode.)

I have emacs key bindings option turned on, but `M-f` and `M-b` don't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold <kbd>alt</kbd> and press the arrow keys, e.g.

<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>

right-arrow will then jump forward between words / spacing, left arrow backward.

---

Is the issue relating to the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key's?

If so - I think the default use / binding of <kbd>ctrl</kbd> will conflict - for example when doing:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>

Another option is to replace <kbd>ctrl</kbd> with *<kbd>alt</kbd>* entirely within:

```
System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Modifier Keys...
```

[image]

On OSX the position and use of the <kbd>alt</kbd> key instead of <kbd>ctrl</kbd> is not intuitive nor helpful.

Its is also most irritating when Mac users try to match a similar scheme on other system's / OS's - instead of opting for proper compliance and preceding standards that continue from the 1970's well before the birth of many younger users or even Apple.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/534499)

Comment: Please elaborate how the provided answer does not adequately answer the question?

Comment: The answer is clear — this also works in almost all OS X apps.

Comment: The answer is clear and correct. It works, but what I was after was a way to get the emacs key binding for move to word to work.